# Reduction of any Arithmetic Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification

Can I make the following claim?

Let $\{ A(k) \}_{1}^n ≡  \{A(k) = a + (k – 1)d\}_{1}^n$ be an arithmetic sequence (AS) with the 1st term = a, and the common difference = d ≠ 0. Such an AS is simply represented by the triple [a, n, d].

Claim:- Every arithmetic sequence, $\{A(k)\}_{1}^n$, can be reduced to the standard sequence $\{k\}_{1}^n$.

Proof:

Step-1: Subtracting the constant ‘a ’ from every term of {A(k)}, we have [0, n, d].

Step-2: Divide every term of the sequence by d, we have [0, n, 1].

Step-3: Adding every term of [0, n, 1] by 1, we have [1, n, 1], which is $\{k\}_1^n$.

Note that when an AS is acted on by any one of the above operations, the nature of the resultant sequence being an AS is preserved.

Answer (score 0):

And what is the purpose of your considerations ?

Example: $A(k)=2+(k-1)5$

By step 1 we get: $B(k)=(k-1)5$.

By step 2 we get $C(k)=k-1$.

And what is now the prize that I have won with these efforts ???

Comment: The answer is :- If this is true, then any (more complicated) AS can be transformed into a much simpler standard one.

Comment: Yes it is true: any AS $A(k)$ can be transformed into a much simpler standard one $C(k)$. And this procedure has a very, very huge advantage: $C(k)$ has nothing to do with $A(k)$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.